# Is something wrong with my GNUstep compiler?

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I tried to compile this code:

```
// Frist program example 

#import Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv [])
{
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool - [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSLog (@"Programming is fun!");

  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

but when I type in the filename an error message shows up from the compiler:

> ./prog1.m: line 1: //: is a directory
>   ./prog1.m: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token '('
>   ./prog1.m: line 6: 'int main (int argc, const char *argv [])'

Comment: It would help if you added how you are invoking the compiler or if you are using a GNUstep Makefile.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a `-` where you want a `=`!

Try this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv [])
{
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSLog (@"Programming is fun!");

  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And an open angle in the import statement. Also the NSString literal should read @"Programming is more fun if you copy/paste"

Comment: Thanks, Firoze! Didn't even catch the bracket.

Comment: Thanks, but it still says ./prog1.m: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token '('
./prog1.m: line 6: 'int main (int argc, const char *argv [])'

Comment: @ivy The problem must be somewhere else in your code, then. I just tested this, and it compiles just fine.